# VBA Outlook script error: an object could not be found

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I am trying to use a VBA script to pull info from the emails in Inbox into an excel spreadsheet:

```
'Subject
'To Address
'From Address
'CC Addresses
```

it fails for senders who have already left the organization and they're no longer in O365.

This is the code bit:

```
Function X400toSMTP(strAdr As String) As String
Dim olkRcp As Outlook.Recipient, olkUsr As Outlook.ExchangeUser
Set olkRcp = Session.CreateRecipient(strAdr)

If olkRcp.AddressEntry = Empty Then
    X400toSMTP = strAdr

ElseIf olkRcp.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
    olkRcp.Resolve
    Set olkUsr = olkRcp.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
    X400toSMTP = olkUsr.PrimarySmtpAddress
End If

Set olkRcp = Nothing
Set olkUsr = Nothing
End Function
```

I ran the debug and it stops at `AddressEntry` : `The attempted operation failed. An object could not be found`
I'm trying to find a way to make the script leave the address field empty for those senders who cannot be found on O365 anymore and further process the rest of the items in the Inbox.

I have tried the below:

```
If IsNull(olkRcp.AddressEntry) Then
    X400toSMTP = strAdr
```

but am still getting the same error for AddressEntry.

I am just a VBA noob so would very much appreciate your advice.

Many thanks!

Comment: you can write `if olkRcp.AddressEntry is nothing then` , or, `if isempty(olkRcp.AddressEntry) then ` , or `if olkRcp.AddressEntry="" then`

Comment: Many thanks, Patrick! I have tried these and it still gives me the error. Maybe it's worth mentioning that I am running this on a shared mailbox. I tried the script on one of the subfolders in my Inbox and it doesn't stop at the leaver address, however it stops at some distribution list that I know it's valid. I also tried enabling 'download shared folders' and still doesn't work for the shared mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the recipient is resolved before accessing the AddressEntry property - call olkRcp.Resolve.

Comment: I did try that, Dmitry. But still getting the same error

Comment: Which method raises that error? Resolve? That means the name cannot be resolved. Can it be resolved in Outlook if you type in the To box and hit Ctrl+K?

Comment: it goes past the resolve somehow. it stops at If olkRcp.AddressEntry Is Nothing Then

Comment: Function X400toSMTP(strAdr As String) As String
    Dim olkRcp As Outlook.Recipient, olkUsr As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Set olkRcp = Session.CreateRecipient(strAdr)
    
    olkRcp.Resolve
    
    If olkRcp.AddressEntry Is Nothing Then
        X400toSMTP = strAdr
    
    ElseIf olkRcp.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
        
        Set olkUsr = olkRcp.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        X400toSMTP = olkUsr.PrimarySmtpAddress
    End If
    
    Set olkRcp = Nothing
    Set olkUsr = Nothing
End Function

Comment: I made it work using error handling :                        Function X400toSMTP(strAdr As String) As String
    Dim olkRcp As Outlook.Recipient, olkUsr As Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Set olkRcp = Session.CreateRecipient(strAdr)
        
    On Error Resume Next
    If olkRcp.AddressEntry.AddressEntryUserType = olExchangeUserAddressEntry Then
        olkRcp.Resolve
        Set olkUsr = olkRcp.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        X400toSMTP = olkUsr.PrimarySmtpAddress
    End If
        
    Set olkRcp = Nothing
    Set olkUsr = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0

End Function